# How to Create GradientBrush around Rectangle

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, border, gradient

In playing around with brushes I was wondering if it is possible to create a GradientBrush that goes around the outside edges of a Windows Phone page. For instance, for each side, the part farthest from the center of the screen would be the device's accent color or a gradient of colors, while the inner part would be PhoneBackgroundBrush or transparent (so a fading effect would be seen). I would only need the gradient to be a very small portion of the entire phone screen, and not stretch into the very center of the screen. I have already got an outline using a border with a gradient brush, but it looks like a flat border on the inside instead of the fading into the page effect I am trying to accomplish. How might I accomplish this task?

MainPage.xaml

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Border BorderThickness="5">
        <Border.BorderBrush>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint=".5,0" EndPoint=".5,1">
                <GradientStop Color="yellow" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="blue" Offset="0.33"/>
                <GradientStop Color="green" Offset="0.66"/>
                <GradientStop Color="red" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Border.BorderBrush>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```